# Change axis for pandas replace ffill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df =
       0    1    2
  0  1.0  2.0  3.0
  1  4.0  5.0  NaN
  2  6.0  NaN  NaN
```

Then it is possible to use `df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)` to obtain:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  5.0
2  6.0  6.0  6.0
```

i.e. I forward fill the rows.
However, now I have a dataframe with `-1` instead of `np.nan`. Pandas has the `replace` function that also has the possibility to use `method='ffill'`, but `replace()` does not take an axis argument, so to obtain the same result as above, I would need to call `df.T.replace(-1, method='ffill').T`. Since transposing is quite expensive (especially considering I'm working on a dataframe of multiple gigabytes), this is not an option. How could I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mask` and `ffill`

```
df.mask(df.eq(-1)).ffill(axis=1)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  5.0
2  6.0  6.0  6.0
```

Comment: Yours as well (-:

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your `-1` values to `NaN` before using [`pd.DataFrame.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
print(df)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0 -1.0
2  6.0 -1.0 -1.0

res = df.replace(-1, np.nan)\
        .ffill(axis=1)

print(res)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  5.0
2  6.0  6.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, use `mask` and `ffill` with `axis=1`:

Where `df1 = df.fillna(-1.0)`

```
df1.mask(df1 == -1).ffill(1)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  5.0
2  6.0  6.0  6.0
```